# From where Function will be inherit and why?

Tags: java, inheritance

Suppose we have one class implements Interface extends abstract class with same abstract function in both Interface and abstract class. Then class inherit which function Interface or abstract class and why.

Like:

```
public class A extends B implements I
{
    public void set()
    {
         // Some code here
    }
}
```

Interface:

```
public interface I {
    public void set();
}
```

abstract Class:

```
 public abstract class B
 {
      public abstract void set();    
 }
```

Comment: Why don't you write some code and try it?

Comment: when you declare a method as abstract ethier class must be interface or abstract class `public abstract class B`

Comment: While interfaces (and their methods) are by definition `abstract` use of that modifier is obsolete; see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.1.1.1

Answer (score 4):

Both. As long as the functions signatures match, the compiler will accept this "double"-inheritance. Keep in mind implementing interface's methods is only a "contract" your class has to verify to be compilable. Implementing the interface only means "my concrete class has to have a method set()". Extending the abstract class B means "my concrete class inherits the method set() from its superclass, and as it's defined as abstract, it needs to implement it". When both these propositions match (as per your example), all is fine.

If there is a difference in the signature of the functions between the interface and the abstract class, your concrete class must then implement both versions.

BTW, slightly off-topic, try to avoid abstract classes as much as you could. If an abstract class has only abstract methods, then it should be an interface. If it has some code in some of its method, then you should probably think about refactoring it to use composition rather than inheritance. Inheritance is evil ;)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter to know from which the method will be inherited because the method in both `Interface` and `Abstract` class are `abstract` meaning no implementation is given.

So all you have to ensure in your concrete class that you must `implement` all the method defined in the interface but not implemented in the abstract class . AND implement all the abstract methods defined in its superclasses (even if they are not defined in an interface) (from Guillaume)

Comment: ...AND implement all the abstract methods defined in its superclasses (even if they are not defined in an interface). In this example, they match, but they may not, in which case you need to implement both.